# Extract phrases in a phragraph based on comma and fullstop as delimiter in python

Tags: python

My input text is like this:

gadhaa krodha se bolaa, jo vyakti jiivita totaa marane kii khabara degaa use bho nahiin: chhod:uun:gaa, kyaa huaa kyaa totaa mara gayaa, lekina huaa kyaa use aao chalakara dekhate hain. vahiin: para nahiin: bataa sakate the ki totaa mara gayaa, yaha tuman: kyaa kaha rahe ho biirabala.

I want output as, one phrase per line:

gadhaa krodha se bolaa,

jo vyakti jiivita totaa marane kii khabara degaa use bho nahiin: chhod:uun:gaa,

kyaa huaa kyaa totaa mara gayaa,

lekina huaa kyaa use aao chalakara dekhate hain.

vahiin: para nahiin: bataa sakate the ki totaa mara gayaa,

yaha tuman: kyaa kaha rahe ho biirabala.

Comment: I have answered you, however I suggest read documentation, use google and if none of them is a help, then came here, otherwise people will give -1 to your questions

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in re.split("[,.]", text):
    print(line)
```

Or alternatively:

```
print("\n".join(re.split("[,.]", text)))
```

Comment: This is a better answer

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple for statement

```
for line in text.split(','):
    # Replace multiple dots with space
    line = re.sub('\.\.+', ' ', line) 
    # Remove single dots
    line = re.sub('\.', '', line)
    # or append wht is needed to replace
    print line
```

Comment: doesn't handle full-stop

Comment: yes, well was the simplest way, cause the question is no so specific

Comment: in the title it says "comma and fullstop as delimiter"